# Which of the following is grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, articles, definite-article, zero-article

Talking on the phone or Talking on phone. 
Do they have different nuances? If so, then which one should be used when and under what circumstances?

Answer (score 5):

The nuance is that ***talking on phone*** is just not correct everyday English. You need a definite article there. The reason why is because ***to talk on the phone*** is a set phrase that can't be changed. You can, however, replace ***on*** with ***over***:

> I was talking **over** the phone with my friend from San Fransisco the other day and he said that they were expecting a minor earthquake.

Answer (score 1):

> "I am talking on the phone.

...is the better choice of the two options.

Other common variations:

> "I am on the phone."
>
> "I am making a phone call."
>
> "I'm talking to Tom on the phone."
>
> "I'm talking with Tom on the phone."
>
> "I'm on the phone with Tom."
>
> "I'm calling Tom."

Answer (score 1):

> Talking on phone

and other expressions that do not use articles where we would expect them are written in a style  called *[headlinease](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese)*<sup>1</sup>. This type of writing is characterized by the removal of words that do not, by themselves,  contain "content". For example, as Professor  John Lawler has stated, *the* in and of itself does not mean anything.

So, you could use *talking on phone* anytime you want to communicate bare  content. Like in a text or on a sign:

> Talking on phone. Please wait.

Using headlinese style in an ordinary conversation might be considered abrupt or  strange.

The other  clause, with  the definite article, is  an example of *[conversational deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/66994/210913)*, in which  the clause's subject  is deleted because it is understood; so it can  be used without the subject explicitly stated, as in

> {I'm/he's/she's/they're/Clare's/Shivam's} talking on the phone.

For example:

> What's John doing?
>   Talking on the phone.

You don't need to explicitly state *John* in the reply,   because it's clear from context that you're talking about John.

As the name *conversational deletion* implies, this sort of thing is used in everyday conversation. It's not necessary to use it, though. It's a little informal. One probably wouldn't say it in formal situations, such as when you're talking to someone in authority.

Otherwise we would expect to encounter the string  *talking on the phone* in everyday usage with the subject explicitly stated:

> She's talking on the phone.

So,   they're both "grammatically correct" when used in the proper context.

---

<sup>1</sup> I dislike using Wikipedia entries as references  because they are often unreliable and contain outdated information, but I can't find an alternative readily available source. The pdf [Article drop in English headlinese](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://folk.ntnu.no/andrewww/Weir-2009-headlinese.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwir0sCh2uHXAhUPxGMKHf15DXI4ChAWCDcwBw&usg=AOvVaw2RqkxI3NTSPN3KAkg1Qy-U) might be of interest.